# Trying to figure out Regular Expression syntax regarding the Single Quote

Tags: regex

I am working on a presentation regarding Regular Expressions. While trying to break down the expression for an Internet Email Address I have figured out what most of it is aside from the single quote ('). Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. The expression is as follows.

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

Comment: can you explain what your problem with the single quote is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: I don't think he means that he has a problem - he simply wants to know what the symbol means.

Comment: This is pretty heavily dependent on the language... or are you wondering what the single quote does?

Comment: I am just trying to get the syntax down. I understand and have found definitions for \w, (), [] and so on but not for the single quote. Also I am working in C#.

Comment: Single quotes aren't syntactically significant in regular expressions. It's just a literal `'`.

Comment: Frankie, yes that is all I am trying to find out.

Comment: `'` is a valid character in an email address, just uncommon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression does not correspond very well to the actual address specification, but it is true that `'` is just an ordinary allowed character in the local part of an email address, and that's presumably why the RE includes it.

In fact, `'` can begin or end an address so it's incorrect for that RE to insist that it appear only within the local part. OTOH, `.` cannot begin or end the local part, so it's somewhat correct that the RE insists it be surrounded by word characters.

(A fairly easy-to-read *informational* RFC that describes address syntax is [RFC 3696.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696))

Answer (score 0):

`'` has no special meaning. The regular expression just says that single quotes can be in a valid e-mail address's username, so as long as they come after at least one word character and before at least one word character. For example this is a valid address, according to this regex: `a'b'c@xyz.com`.

Comment: Thanks very much. This was quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Anything inside of the brackets is literally allowed, so they're literally accepting an apostrophe for cases where you would have a name like:

```
c.o'neil@somewebsite.com
```